# ng-repeat not working consistently with arrays of items

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have two arrays of strings that I want to repeat within my page. Here are the arrays (infoData and modelData) in the debugger:

Screenshot of arrays in Chrome inspector:

[image: screenshot]

Here is my html:

```
<div ng-repeat="info in pTab.infoData">
    <p>{{info}}</p>
</div>

<div ng-repeat="stats in pTab.modelData">  
    <p>{{stats}}</p>
</div>
```

However the page only displays the contents of infoData as shown below:

```
XPE

www.sampleurl.com

Sample summary has nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat...
```

My question is why does this happen and how can I get the elements of the second array to display like the first?

Here is some additional info that may be useful to you. As I was trying out different things this struck me as interesting:

The following HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="info in pTab.infoData">
    <p>{{pTab.infoData}}</p>
</div>

<div ng-repeat="stats in pTab.modelData">  
    <p>{{pTab.modelData}}</p>
</div>
```

displays the infoData array in square brackets as a string 3 times (infoData has a length of 3).While the following HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="info in pTab.infoData">
    <p>{{pTab.modelData}}</p>
</div>

<div ng-repeat="stats in pTab.modelData">  
    <p>{{pTab.infoData}}</p>
</div>
```

displays the modelData array in square brackets as a string 3 times.

Is there something wrong with the `<div ng-repeat="stats in pTab.modelData">`? Because whatever is in that div never repeats, even if I move that div ahead of the `<div ng-repeat="stats in pTab.modelData">`

If I'm being unclear or you'd like to see more of the code, please let me know. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Please provide a Plunkr demonstrating the issue. Is there any other data binding on the page? Is there any errors in the console.

Comment: Yes, show the entire html and also the controller where the data is.

Answer (score 1):

If you look in browser console you can see error like this

> Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: stats in pTab.modelData, Duplicate key: string:0.1 mg, Duplicate value: 0.1 mg

So, you have duplicated items in your second array, and for resolve this error should use *track by* expression, in this case enough *$index*

```
<div ng-repeat="stats in pTab.modelData track by $index">
```

A bit more about it you can see in doc: [Tracking and Duplicates](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#tracking-and-duplicates)

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.pTab = {
      modelData: [
        '0.1 mg',
        '0.1 mg',
        '0.1 mg'
      ]
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller='ctrl'>
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  <div ng-repeat="stats in pTab.modelData track by $index">
    <p>{{stats}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```